# Keycloak Adapter Failed to verify token when deploy Springboot webapp to Docker

Tags: docker, keycloak

I am developing a Springboot app and a React frontend running on Tomcat, together with Hasura Graphql and Keycloak. All 3 items are running in one Docker stack with following stack.yml:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  timescale-primary:
    image: timescale-replication:latest
    env_file:
      - primary.env
    networks:
      - public-network
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - timescale-primary-storage:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.labels.type == primary

  timescale-replica:
    image: timescale-replication:latest
    env_file:
      - replica.env
    networks:
      - public-network
    volumes:
      - timescale-replica-storage:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.labels.type != primary

  hasura:
    image: hasura/graphql-engine
    networks:
      - public-network
    ports:
      - 6080:8080
    env_file:
      - hasura.env
    volumes:
      - hasura-storage:/var/lib/hasura
    depends_on:
      - timescale-primary

  keycloak:
    image: keycloak
    networks:
      - public-network
    ports:
      - 9080:8080
    env_file:
      - keycloak.env
    volumes:
      - keycloak-storage:/opt/jboss/keycloak/themes
    depends_on:
      - timescale-primary

  tomcat:
    image: tomcat:v1
    networks:
      - public-network
    ports:
      - 8086:8080
    volumes:
      - tomcat-storage:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps:Z
      - tomcat-log-storage:/var/log/tomcat:Y

networks:
  public-network:

volumes:
  timescale-primary-storage:
  timescale-replica-storage:
  hasura-storage:
  keycloak-storage:
  tomcat-storage:
  tomcat-log-storage:
```

The SpringBoot webapp is a graphql server running under http://tomcat:8080/backend, and the React app is deployed under http://tomcat:8080/ui.

Inside Hasura, I setup a remote schema to point to that server: http://tomcat:8080/backend/graphql, with all client headers forwarded.

Basically, the React app access "backend" indirectly via Hasura.

In Keycloak, I have setup a public client for the "ui" app, and a confidential client for the "backend" app.

I then get the authentication flow as follows:

1. On docker's host machine, call http://localhost:8086/ui
2. Forwarded to localhost:9080/auth/... (Keycloak's login screen)
3. After successful login, redirected to the "ui" app
4. The React app calls Hasura
5. Hasura calls "backend" and gets "Failed to verify token", "Invalid authorization header, see WWW-Authenticate header for details"

```
2019-12-09 02:47:59.163 DEBUG 1 --- [io-8080-exec-30] o.k.adapters.PreAuthActionsHandler       : adminRequest http://tomcat:8080/backend/graphql
2019-12-09 02:47:59.164 DEBUG 1 --- [io-8080-exec-30] f.KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter : Request is to process authentication
2019-12-09 02:47:59.164 DEBUG 1 --- [io-8080-exec-30] f.KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter : Attempting Keycloak authentication
2019-12-09 02:47:59.165 TRACE 1 --- [io-8080-exec-30] o.k.adapters.RequestAuthenticator        : --> authenticate()
2019-12-09 02:47:59.165 TRACE 1 --- [io-8080-exec-30] o.k.adapters.RequestAuthenticator        : try bearer
2019-12-09 02:47:59.165 DEBUG 1 --- [io-8080-exec-30] o.k.a.BearerTokenRequestAuthenticator    : Found [1] values in authorization header, selecting the first value for Bearer.
2019-12-09 02:47:59.165 DEBUG 1 --- [io-8080-exec-30] o.k.a.BearerTokenRequestAuthenticator    : Verifying access_token
2019-12-09 02:47:59.165 TRACE 1 --- [io-8080-exec-30] o.k.a.BearerTokenRequestAuthenticator    :        access_token: eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJyb1NzQ2I1VWJPeDYyZHltWThzUm9qR2lGMHpINDJXQWdOU0JFd0Q2TEFFIn0.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.signature
2019-12-09 02:47:59.167 DEBUG 1 --- [io-8080-exec-30] o.k.a.BearerTokenRequestAuthenticator    : Failed to verify token
2019-12-09 02:47:59.167 DEBUG 1 --- [io-8080-exec-30] o.k.adapters.RequestAuthenticator        : Bearer FAILED
2019-12-09 02:47:59.167 DEBUG 1 --- [io-8080-exec-30] f.KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter : Auth outcome: FAILED
2019-12-09 02:47:59.167 DEBUG 1 --- [io-8080-exec-30] f.KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter : Authentication request failed: org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.KeycloakAuthenticationException: Invalid authorization header, see WWW-Authenticate header for details

org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.KeycloakAuthenticationException: Invalid authorization header, see WWW-Authenticate header for details
        at org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter.attemptAuthentication(KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:158) ~[keycloak-spring-security-adapter-7.0.0.jar:7.0.0]
```

If I put the React and Springboot app in a Tomcat installed directly onto Docker's host machine, the authentication into the backend was fine. This issue only occurred when everything is deployed into Docker.

I'm new to Keycloak and Docker, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for authentication to work, the URL to Keycloak needs to be the same for the React app and the springboot app. I.e. you can't use localhost for one and Docker container name for the other.

In my case, either a public IP or actual domain name can be used.

Comment: I am getting the same problem that the token generating at web-app was not working in my backend-app. I am testing it at localhost so the web-app is running at url(http://localhost:8090/) and the backend-app is running on url(http://localhost:8080/) under the same realm. So what else i be missing here?